# How to fix executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3 && pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45']:

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, pip

I am getting this when running a Dockerfile.
When I reseted my windows it worked but recently I deleted all docker containers and when I tried to build from the Dockerfile again, I got this issue. I can't upgrade pip or do pip install.
Here is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DOCKER_STATE dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python-pip python-dev uwsgi-plugin-python \
    nginx supervisor libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev mysql-client \
    libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev uwsgi python-mysqldb libmysqlclient-dev \
    imagemagick poppler-utils curl


RUN pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3 && pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45'
```

And here is the error I am getting

```
#7 [ 3/20] RUN pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3 && pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45'
#7 sha256:2623dbc50626ca8f0979fcda52fc07d026edc413a5da1187d9d4a1fcae0edfd8
#7 0.525 Downloading/unpacking pip==9.0.3
#7 1.162   Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
#7 1.740   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip==9.0.3
#7 1.740 Cleaning up...
#7 1.740 No distributions at all found for pip==9.0.3
#7 1.742 Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
#7 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3 && pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45']: exit code: 1
------
 > [ 3/20] RUN pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3 && pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45':
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3 && pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45']: exit code: 1
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It says there `No distributions at all found for pip==9.0.3`.
So just install the latest version (you have no disadvantages from `pip 21.1.2`).
Do `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and everything should work

Comment: It still doesn't work. Here is what it brings when I run it                                                        
.#7 [3/3] RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
#7 ...............
#7 1.380 No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
#7 1.381 Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
#7 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python -m pip install --upgrade pip]: exit code: 1

Comment: Is it possible that you are using a newer Ubuntu version in the container?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14. Should I go with lower version or newer version?

Comment: Newer is pretty much always better. Unless you have to have it for technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was the base image I was using.
Once I changed it to a working one the error disappeared.
I specifically used a `python3.9.10-slim` image from our local repo. Once I switched to the regular `python3.9.0` image all worked well.

The `python3.9.10-slim` image being corrupted is a problem in our repo but maybe what you're experiencing is caused by the same type of issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).